# Visual Studio 2022 WPF Setup with offline prerequisites

Tags: c#, wpf, setup-project

I've been trying to create an offline installer for my WPF project using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer addon for VS 2022. For some reason no matter what I do, I cannot get it to recognize the packages I've manually downloaded and added to all sorts of locations on my PC.

I've seen some people saying I should go to Microsoft SDK -> ClickOnce Bootstrapper -> Packages and place the correct packages in their correct folders, which I believe I had done.

Here's the properties window for the Setup Project:

[image]

Here's the actual error lines from VS 2022:

```
ERROR: To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'net6coreruntime_x64\dotnet-runtime-6.0.15-win-x64.exe' for item '.NET Runtime 6.0.15 (x64)' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.
ERROR: To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'net6coreruntime_x86\dotnet-runtime-6.0.15-win-x86.exe' for item '.NET Runtime 6.0.15 (x86)' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.
ERROR: To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'net6desktopruntime_x64\windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.15-win-x64.exe' for item '.NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.15 (x64)' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.
ERROR: To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'net6desktopruntime_x86\windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.15-win-x86.exe' for item '.NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.15 (x86)' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.
ERROR: General failure building bootstrapper
```

And I have followed the exact names stated in these messages and the exact folder names. So for the first message, folder name "net6coreruntime_x64" and file name "dotnet-runtime-6.0.15-win-x64.exe".

I've placed these files in the following locations, yet nothing worked:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX472

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX472\en

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\vcredist_x64

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\vcredist_x64\en

Also placed them in the project folder.

Nothing I've been doing works, and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
Matt